OPENAI API: Как решить проблему на NodeJS: 403 Country, region, or territory not supported


import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({apiKey: 'sk-*******'});

async function main() {
   const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      messages: [{ role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' }],
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
   });

   console.log(completion.choices[0]);
}

main();
PermissionDeniedError: 403 Country, region, or territory not supported
    at APIError.generate (file:///K:/JS/openai2/node_modules/openai/error.mjs:46:20)
    at OpenAI.makeStatusError (file:///K:/JS/openai2/node_modules/openai/core.mjs:256:25)
    at OpenAI.makeRequest (file:///K:/JS/openai2/node_modules/openai/core.mjs:299:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getGptResponse (file:///K:/JS/openai2/index.js:27:24) {
  status: 403,
  headers: {
    'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400',
    'cf-ray': '86fa96c54af49d56-DME',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    date: 'Fri, 05 Apr 2024 15:32:06 GMT',
    server: 'cloudflare',
    'set-cookie': '__cf_bm=KPvuJkpFci9jxNT.zxe35R4nZRXh6Mp_RAQekc8JXFw-1712331126-1.0.1.1-oGOdyNmDoixQ4J2cBAJbAVfIHckBOo6yV_DmpvxlRCvSGUuN_pQcxnR2BuIhseEgv_DtYw.Kj0h4YO7gOrPKZg; path=/; expires=Fri, 05-Apr-24 16:02:06 GMT; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding'
  },
  error: {
    message: 'Country, region, or territory not supported',
    type: 'request_forbidden',
    param: null,
    code: 'unsupported_country_region_territory'
  },
  code: 'unsupported_country_region_territory',
  param: null,
  type: 'request_forbidden'
}



У меня есть прокси, но как их подключить в коде - не знаю. Подскажите.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

If you would like to customize this behavior, for example to use the API behind a proxy, you can pass an httpAgent which is used for all requests https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai#:~:text=Agent%20(e.g.%2C-,for%20proxies,-)

Если вы используете эту библиотеку openai, то на странице документации прямо указано как использовать прокси (под заголовком Configuring an HTTP(S) Agent (e.g., for proxies)):
import http from 'http';
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'https-proxy-agent';

// Configure the default for all requests:
const openai = new OpenAI({
  httpAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://168.63.76.32:3128'),
});

Перед использованием не забудьте установить https-proxy-agent:
npm i https-proxy-agent

и замените http://168.63.76.32:3128 на адрес и порт своего прокси

Благодарю! Помогло!
